# Show notification except in lock screen

Tags: android, notifications

I need to set Priority of notification to Max to show in big content. But this cause to show notification in lock screen. How can I prevent it form showing in lock screen?
This method doesn't support all android apis

```
.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setPublicVersion` with `setVisibility` in `Notification.Builder` class. Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setVisibility(int)

Comment: I pass null argument to setPublicVersion but again shows notification

Comment: pass `VISIBILITY_SECRET` in the argument instead of `null`

Comment: it's argument is Notification nor int.

Comment: the value for `VISIBILITY_SECRET` is -1, whereas for `VISIBILITY_PUBLIC` its 1 & for `VISIBILITY_PRIVATE` its 0.

Comment: Notification.Builder setPublicVersion (Notification n).   see input please

Comment: use this `notificationBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET);`

Comment: this method only works for api >= 21, I want to work in all apis